# Computing min and max values of a matrix

Tags: math, matrix

This question might be closed as it sounds vague but I'm really asking this because I have no idea or my math background is not sufficient enough.

I'm trying to implement a challenge and a part of the challenge requires me to compute min and max values of a matrix. I have no trouble with matrix implementations and its operations however **what** is the min and max values of a matrix? Considering a 3x3 matrix is the min the smallest number among 9 numbers and max is the greatest or something else?

Comment: bitmask below is correct; there's no one right answer to this problem.  The "challenge" you're trying to implement should either be explicit about what's meant by the maximum value of a matrix, or it should be clear from context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends. The maximum could be the maximum entry, or the entry with the maximum absolute value or it could be the row (col) vector that is largest with respect to some norm.